# ArmDeploymentCollection Not in Azure.ResourceManager.Resources Namespace

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, sdk, azure-resource-manager

I am following the new [Azure.ResourceManager SDK examples here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/resources/Azure.ResourceManager.Resources/samples/Sample2_ManagingDeployments.md).

I'm not seeing classes I'd expect to see in Azure.ResourceManager.Resources. Specifically, ArmDeploymentCollection and ResourceGroupResource doesn't have a GetArmDeployments() method.

Azure.ResourceManager installed is Azure.ResourceManager.1.0.0. I'm targeting .NET framework 4.8.

I've tried uninstalling/re-installing Azure.ResourceManager several times, but doesn't change anything.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using System.Threading;
using Azure;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources.Models;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            // Authenticate
            var credentials = new DefaultAzureCredential();

            await RunSample(credentials);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utilities.Log(ex);
        }

    }

    public static async Task RunSample(TokenCredential credential)
    {

        try
        {
            var deploymentName = "bradDeployment";
            var rgName = "rg-percipience-test-002";
            var subscriptionId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID");
            var templateJson = Utilities.GetArmTemplate("ArmTemplate.json");

            ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
            SubscriptionResource subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
            ResourceGroupCollection rgCollection = subscription.GetResourceGroups();
            // With the collection, we can create a new resource group with an specific name
            AzureLocation location = AzureLocation.EastUS;
            ArmOperation<ResourceGroupResource> lro = await rgCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, rgName, new ResourceGroupData(location));
            ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = lro.Value;
            
            Utilities.Log("Created a resource group with name: " + rgName);
            
            // Create a deployment for an Azure App Service via an ARM
            // template.
            
            Utilities.Log("Starting a deployment for an Azure App Service: " + deploymentName);

            // First we need to get the deployment collection from the resource group
            ArmDeploymentCollection armDeploymentCollection = resourceGroup.GetArmDeployments();
            // Use the same location as the resource group
            // Passing string to template and parameters
            var input = new ArmDeploymentContent(new ArmDeploymentProperties(ArmDeploymentMode.Incremental)
            {
                Template = BinaryData.FromString(File.ReadAllText("storage-template.json")),
                Parameters = BinaryData.FromString(File.ReadAllText("storage-parameters.json"))
            });
            ArmOperation<ArmDeploymentResource> lro2 = await ArmDeploymentCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, deploymentName, input);
            ArmDeploymentResource deployment = lro2.Value;

            Utilities.Log("Completed the deployment: " + deploymentName);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                Utilities.Log("Deleting Resource Group: " + rgName);

                await (await resourceGroups.StartDeleteAsync(rgName)).WaitForCompletionAsync();

                Utilities.Log("Deleted Resource Group: " + rgName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utilities.Log(ex);
            }
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please pate code rather than image ? it will be easier if someone would like to reproduce locally. Also you probably want to check the associated github repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Azure.ResourceManager.Resources_1.0.0/sdk/resources/Azure.ResourceManager.Resources. Maybe the class you're expecting don't exists yet.

Comment: You're trying to get existing deployments ?

Comment: Code pasted. I'm trying to emulate this example to deploy resources via ARM templates: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/resources/Azure.ResourceManager.Resources/samples/Sample2_ManagingDeployments.md.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding a reference to Azure.ResourceManager.Resources.dll. Not sure why this reference isn't added when the nuget package is installed.