# Types and namespaces not found when targeting a NetStandard 2 NuGet package from Net Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

I've inherited a .Net Framework 4.8 app. I'm adding some functionality which requires me to add some NuGet packages that target .Net Standard 2.0.

The packages I'm trying to install are:

- Azure.Core
- Azure.Identity
- Azure.ResourceManager
- Azure.ResourceManager.Resources

Of these, all but the first simply target .Net Standard 2.0. (Azure.Core additionally targets .Net Core, .Net Framework, .Net5...)

All except the last one seem to play nicely with my .Net Framework 4.8 application. It's just Azure.ResourceManager.Resources that won't work. When I try to use the types it is supposed to provide, I get the greatest hits of targeting errors, such as...

> The type or namespace name 'ArmDeploymentContent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And

> 'ResourceGroupResource' does not contain a definition for 'GetArmDeployments' and no accessible extension method 'GetArmDeployments' accepting a first argument of type 'ResourceGroupResource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I think I've checked all the basics:

- I've definitely included a "using" statement (and in any case, intellisense would normally suggest this if I hadn't)
- The package works when called from a project targeting another framework (.Net5 specifically)
- I double checked that .Net Framework 4.8 is supposed to be compatible with .Net Standard 2.0 ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0#select-net-standard-version))
- I've removed and re-added the packages, as well as running `Update-Package -reinstall`
- I've restarted Visual Studio and even my PC.

Before I file a bug report somewhere (where?!), can anyone tell me what's going on here? Or even what to try next?

[image: Screenshot of some code with red squiggles]

Comment: Can you explicitly reference `Azure.ResourceManager.Resources.dll` ? ([See this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72160922/armdeploymentcollection-not-in-azure-resourcemanager-resources-namespace))

Comment: @MatthewWatson This is why I love Stack Overflow. Adding that explicitly did help! I'm still a little worried about having to do this on each dev/build machine, so will still raise a bug with MS. Want to convert your comment to an answer for me to accept?

Comment: Bug created here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/29645

Comment: I think that my answer is really a duplicate of the one that I linked, so I'll close this question as a duplicate since it appears it really does have the same answer.

Comment: That's fair. Thanks again!